# YAML error- expected <'document start'>, but found <'block mapping start'>

Tags: syntax, yaml, filesystems, config

A Bash command I'm running is supposed to update a YAML file.

The YAML file is as follows-

```
---
[conf]

users:
  - mitchell
```

I get the error-

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  expected '<document start>', but found '<block mapping start>'

The offending line appears to be:

users:
^ here
```

What should I do?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

`[conf]` in YAML is a *flow sequence* consisting of a sequence start indicator (`[`), one item (the scalar `conf`), and a sequence end indicator (`]`).

Since a YAML document can only have one root node, the document is finished after `]`. A YAML file allows you to have multiple documents in it, separated by `---` (and optionally `...`). So for example, this would be valid YAML:

```yaml
---
[conf]
---
users:
  - mitchell
```

Since a separator is missing, your YAML parser complains that it expected the start of a new document but found more content in the current document whose root node has already been closed.

Chances are that you expect `[conf]` to be a special syntax for a section like e.g. in INI files. But it isn't. To put the following content into a section, you'd simply do

```yaml
conf:
  users:
    - mitchell
```